Cannot enable automatic login in Ubuntu Studio 22.04
The system does not have a /etc/gdm3 directory.
The System User dialog does not have an Unlock... button. Account type is Administrator. See screenshot.
Screenshot of System information

>>cat /etc/X11/default-display-manager
/usr/bin/sddm

/etc/sddm.conf
Session=Ubuntu
[Autologin]
User=allelopath



Automatically login as user


Yes, I have added to question

What is the behavior in the Login Screen (SDDM) setting under Users - System Settings?

I've added a couple more screenshots. If these don't answer your question, could you please provide more info

What I'm wondering about is the setting that lets you adjust automatic login behavior, like seen here - https://www.simplified.guide/kde/automatic-login

Ah ok I've added that screenshot. You can see that it is set to automatically login. But that isn't happening.
